# How to check slow_query for a project?

Tags: mysql, wampserver, mysql-slow-query-log

I just came across a very useful feature which is `slow_query_log` that checks queries that run slowly. I managed to execute the commands in the CMD following this link:

> https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/enabling-the-slow-query-log-in-mysql

the log file is created inside a project folder, and no queries found in it, so there should be no slow queries.

However I'm trying to understand how this `slow_query_log` checks, per **database**, per **project**?

If I want to check slow queries for a specific project what command should I type? How will the slow_query thingy know where all the queries are listed in my myproject thus what are the queries run throughout?

> Please explain this part to me.

This is how I executed the commands in CMD:

```
cd C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.14/bin
mysql -u myusername-p
enter password: mypassword
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON';
SET GLOBAL long_query_time = 5;
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log_file = 'C:/wamp/www/myproject/slow_query/log.php';
```

Then I exit the CMD, and returning typed, `mysql SELECT SLEEP(6);`

I found the following in the `slow_query/log.php` file

> wampmysqld, Version: 5.7.14 (MySQL Community Server (GPL)). started
>   with: TCP Port: 3306, Named Pipe: /tmp/mysql.sock Time
>   Id Command    Argument

Comment: The log is global, but you can filter it with something like `grep`. Out of curiosity, why log. **php** ?

Comment: @AlexBlex I simply named in php extension. No idea if I should save in any other extension.please advise.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension

Comment: @AlexBlex, how can I use grep for a particular project?

Comment: by a pattern specific to a project

Comment: Try something a little longer like SLEEP(10).

I followed your steps and got this


    # Time: 170629 16:43:24
    # User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
    # Query_time: 10.019652  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  
    Rows_examined: 0
    SET timestamp=1498754604;
    SELECT SLEEP(10);

Comment: @DanHawkins, appreciated if you could explain how my code above checks sql? Is it checking for all databases? How can I check for a particular project.

Comment: AH. I see. Well, like @AlexBlex mentioned, this is a global log. So, every slow query, regardless of project, will be reported here. I do not believe there is configurable way to generate multiple slow query logs. I would suggest creating a database per project. Then, you can parse the slow query log for each database.

Comment: For 5.6 and newer, you also need 

    log_output = FILE  -- or FILE,TABLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to use a slow-query analyzer.

The one that I find best it's Percona's **pt-query-digest** which enables you to filter and analyze the slow log in many different ways. This tool is included in [Percona's Toolkit](https://www.percona.com/software/database-tools/percona-toolkit) which has many useful tools for MySQL DBAs

Now I'm assuming you want to filter the logs per schema/database (Project it's an alien concept in MySQL), if so you would use pt-query-digest using the `--filter '($event->{db} || "") =~ m/mydb/'` option where mydb is the database you want to filter.

You can read more useful information on the slow query log in Percona's blogs like [this one](http://www.percona.com/blog/2014/03/14/mysql-slow-query-log-tools-and-tips/)

Comment: thanks for explaining in detail. Kindly help to enlighten me a bit more on it. So to check which query slows run, I need to run one query after another?

Comment: The slow-query-logs writes to it's file any query that takes more than long_query_time seconds along with useful information, it doesn't care about databases or projects. You can only filter it afterwards when you are analyzing the written file. If you want to understand why a query runs slow then you need to look at the EXPLAIN command.